# Dynamic bandwidth limitation with pfSense

Tags: traffic-shaping, bandwidth-control

Currently we have a squid proxy to access internet. A single download can saturate the lines and in this circumstance a second user experiences extremely poor performance trying to surf the web.

I try to better clarify what I'm complaining about.

If a second download is launched after few seconds the available bandwidth is almost equally divided between the two download and it is ok. 
Instead accessing web pages is a real pain. I suppose it depends to the fact that in order to visualize a web page lots of connections are established and each of them is delayed due to line saturation.

Can PfSense help in improving the performances in this scenario ?
Don't want to create priority classes for certain users or computers. What I would like to achieve is that the creation of new connections is not delayed by an existing one which goes at full speed and that the available bandwidth is equally divided (which already happens, but only after the new connection is established).

I would be glad to be pointed to a working configuration for PfSense in order to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

The traffic shaping algorithm are always complicated to manage and squid don't help you so much , I know what you mean.
You need to use iptables and tc commands and going in the deep , may be you can find some ready to use scripts.
In any case I have tested PFsense and of course it's a great product, but if you don't want drive crazy I try to suggest smoothwall (free) , I got some of them in production and it seems that work better in this case.
Regards